# no such file or directory, stat '/vercel/path0/.vercel/output/functions/n/[[...index]].func'

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, next.js, vercel

I don't know what is the problem here [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGmZn.png)

Running build in Washington, D.C., USA (East) – iad1
Retrieving list of deployment files...
Skipping build cache, deployment was triggered without cache.
Downloading 1448 deployment files...
Using prebuilt build artifacts...
[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/vercel/path0/.vercel/output/functions/n/[[...index]].func'] {
errno: -2,
code: 'ENOENT',
syscall: 'stat',
path: '/vercel/path0/.vercel/output/functions/n/[[...index]].func'
}

I am tri

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.